# Create points from addresses in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, address

I have a CSV with multiple addresses in the form (city, zipcode, street, number (possibly with address supplement ["A", "F", etc.].

Is there any way to create points on these addresses QGIS? The reason I came up with this, is the fact I can look up addresses in QGIS using the search bar in the bottom left corner of QGIS.

I am aware that coordinates are easier but I have a few thousand addresses so it is impossible to do this by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The technical term is "**geocoding**". If you search the Internet for `QGIS geocoding` you will find a lot of information.

GDAL/OGR, which is used extensively in QGIS, has a geocoding function called `ogr_geocode`:

https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html#ogr-geocoding-functions, https://erouault.blogspot.com/2012/12/a-geocoding-client-api-in-gdalogr.html

You could use QGIS´ command line shell to fetch the locations for your addresses and store the results in a GeoPackage database file:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG cities.gpkg -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ogr_geocode(street||' '||number||' '||zipcode||' '||city) as geom,street,number,zipcode,city from cities" cities.csv -nln cities
```

But be aware that `ogr_geocode` uses `OpenStreetMap Nominatim` for geocoding. In accordance with their policy, only 1 call per second is allowed (https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/)